# Is it possible to generate custom configuration of table using tinymce?

Tags: tinymce

A table of two raw by tinymce:

```
<table style="width: 100%;" border="1">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="width: 33.3333%;"></td>
<td style="width: 33.3333%;"></td>
<td style="width: 33.3333%;"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="width: 33.3333%;"></td>
<td style="width: 33.3333%;"></td>
<td style="width: 33.3333%;"></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I can add new class and attributes and reform this default table structure. But is it possible to add   etc? for example I want to generate the following bootstrap table:

```
    <table style="width: 100%;" class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
    <tr>
    <th style="width: 33.3333%;"></th>
    <th style="width: 33.3333%;"></th>
    <th style="width: 33.3333%;"></th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
   <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td style="width: 33.3333%;"></td>
    <td style="width: 33.3333%;"></td>
    <td style="width: 33.3333%;"></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

I can add this class `'table table-bordered'`. I can't add `<thead>,<th>`. I read the documentation of tinymce and googling for 2 days. Know I have come to a conclusion - I will stop if it is actually not possible. Any help is appreciated. Thanks for your time.

Comment: if you add a table and then right click on the row you want to make the header row and go Row > Row Properties you can change the row type to header. IS that what you were looking for or did you want to add the able with a header row already in it by default?

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know this trick to make a row header as this awesome way. You make my day.